# Return.Page Account ID

Tags: class, salesforce

How can I add to **return.page** syntax the **account id**.
My code below doesn't work.

```
public class BAW3_class {

private Id accId {get; set;}
public BAW3_class(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) { 
    accId = stdcontroller.getRecord().Id;
}  

public Decimal testValue { get; set; }

public PageReference nextPage () {    

    if(testValue == null) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Required value'));
        return null;
    }        

    testValue += 500;

    return Page.BAW3?id=accid;    
}
```

It is possible to add the ID to the string **Page.BAW3?id=.......**

Thanks,
Sascha

**EDIT 18.03.2015**

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Below I will post the whole code again.
I hope this will help to find the problem.
I just get a page with the value. But I need also the information from the account.

**Visualforce: Page to show the result**

```
<apex:page controller="Bestandsauswertung3_class" showheader="false"     sidebar="false">

  {!testvalue}
  <br/>
  <apex:dataTable value="{!AccList}" var="Record">
  {!Record.Name}
  </apex:dataTable>

</apex:page>
```

**Visualforce: Prepage to add the value**

```
<apex:page controller="Bestandsauswertung3_class" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Baw 1" subtitle="Next page test" />
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageMessages id="messages" />
      <apex:pageBlock >
                     <apex:commandbutton value="Wert für SV-Ersparnis" action="{!nextPage}" />
          <apex:inputText value="{!testValue}" />
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Class**

```
public class Bestandsauswertung3_class {

private Id accId {get; set;}
    Public List<Account> AccList {get; set;}
public Bestandsauswertung3_class() { 
    accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    AccList = [SELECT Name, NumberOfEmployees FROM Account WHERE Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId]; 

    AnteilM = 0;
    AnteilF = 0;

    getEZRen();   

}

public Integer AnteilM {get; set;}
public Integer AnteilF {get; set;}

public Decimal testValue { get; set; }

public PageReference nextPage () {    

    if(testValue == null) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Required value'));
        return null;
    }        

   testValue += 500;
   return new PageReference('/apex/Bestandsauswertung3?id='+accid);   
} 


public void getEZRen() {

List<Einzelrisiko__c> EZRList = [SELECT Geschlecht__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId];

    FOR (Einzelrisiko__c EZR : EZRList) {  

    IF(EZR.Geschlecht__c == 'W') { AnteilF++; } 
    IF(EZR.Geschlecht__c == 'M') { AnteilM++; }  

} }

}
```

Comment: Could some one take a look to the code. I need this setting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming BAW3 is your VF page..

Do the following:

```
return new PageReference('/apex/BAW3?id='+accid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I get an error SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.NumberOfEmployees

Comment: I posted my whole code. Do you have some more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
return new PageReference('/apex/BAW3?scontrolCaching=1&id='+accid);
```

if this does not work, then you will need to query the database to get your account, but try that before and let me know